# Error while running UDF on dataframe columns

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have extracted some data from hive to dataframe, which is in the below shown format.

```
| NUM_ID|            SIG1|           SIG2|             SIG3|            SIG4|
+----------------------+---------------+--------------------+---------------+
|XXXXX01|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
|XXXXX02|[{15695604780...|[{15695604780...|[{15695604780...|[{15695604780...|
|XXXXX03|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
|XXXXX04|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
|XXXXX05|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
|XXXXX06|[{15695605340...|[{15695605340...|[{15695605340...|[{15695605340...|
|XXXXX07|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
|XXXXX08|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|[{15695605310...|
```

If we take only one signal it will be as below.

```
|XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|
    [{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560481000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|
    [{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560527000,34.7825}]|
    [{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560479000,34.7825},{1569560487000,34.7825}]
```

The schema for the above data is

```
 fromHive.printSchema
root
|-- NUM_ID: string (nullable = true)
|-- SIG1: string (nullable = true)
|-- SIG2: string (nullable = true)
|-- SIG3: string (nullable = true)
|-- SIG4: string (nullable = true)
```

My requirement is to get the all E values from all the columns for a particular NUM_ID and create as a new cloumn with corresponding signal values in another columns as shown below.

```
+-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| NUM_ID|            E| SIG1_V| SIG2_V| SIG3_V| SIG4_V|
+-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|XXXXX01|1569560531000|33.7825|34.7825|   null|96.3354|
|XXXXX01|1569560505000|   null|   null|35.5501|   null|
|XXXXX01|1569560531001|73.7825|   null|   null|   null|
|XXXXX02|1569560505000|34.7825|   null|35.5501|96.3354|
|XXXXX02|1569560531000|33.7825|34.7825|35.5501|96.3354|
|XXXXX02|1569560505001|73.7825|   null|   null|   null|
|XXXXX02|1569560502000|   null|   null|35.5501|96.3354|
|XXXXX03[1569560531000|73.7825|   null|   null|   null|
|XXXXX03|1569560505000|34.7825|   null|35.5501|96.3354|
|XXXXX03|1569560509000|   null|34.7825|35.5501|96.3354|
```

I tried writing UDFs to achieve this as below.

UDF#1:

```
def UDF_E:UserDefinedFunction=udf((r: Row)=>{
val SigColumn = "SIG1,SIG2,SIG3,SIG4,SIG5,SIG6"
val colList = SigColumn.split(",").toList
val rr = "[\\}],[\\{]".r
var out = ""
colList.foreach{ x =>
val a = (rr replaceAllIn(r.getAs(x).toString, "|")).replaceAll("\\[\\{","").replaceAll("\\}\\]","").replaceAll(""""E":""","")
val st = a.split("\\|").map(x => x.split(",")(0)).toSet
out = out + "," + st.mkString(",")
}
val out1 = out.replaceFirst(s""",""","").split(",").toSet.mkString(",")
out1
})
```

UDF#2:

```
def UDF_V:UserDefinedFunction=udf((E: String,SIG:String)=>{
val Signal = SIG.replaceAll("\\{", "\\(").replaceAll("\\}", "\\)").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll(""""E":""","").replaceAll(""","V":""","=")
val SigMap = "(\\w+)=([\\w 0-9 .]+)".r.findAllIn(Signal).matchData.map(i => {(i.group(1), i.group(2))}).toMap
var out = ""
if(SigMap.keys.toList.contains(E)){
out = SigMap(E).toString
}
out})
```

output of UDF#1 is shown as below:

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
    |NUM_ID |SIG1                                                                                          |SIG2                                                                                            |SIG3                                                                                             |SIG4                                                                     |E            |
    +-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560483000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560497000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560475000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560489000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560535000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560531000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560513000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560537000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560491000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560521000|
    |XXXXX01|[{1569560531000,3.7825},{1569560475000,3.7812},{1569560483000,3.7812},{1569560491000,34.7875}]|[{1569560537000,3.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560489000,34.7825},{1569560497000,34.7825}]|[{1569560505000,34.7825},{1569560513000,34.7825},{1569560521000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825}]|[{1569560535000,34.7825},{1569560531000,34.7825},{1569560483000,34.7825}]|1569560505000|
    +-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Output of UDF#2 is:

```
+-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    | NUM_ID|            E| SIG1_V| SIG2_V| SIG3_V| SIG4_V|
    +-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    |XXXXX01|1569560475000| 3.7812|       |       |       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560483000| 3.7812|       |       |34.7825|
    |XXXXX01|1569560489000|       |34.7825|       |       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560491000|34.7875|       |       |       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560497000|       |34.7825|       |       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560505000|       |       |34.7825|       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560513000|       |       |34.7825|       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560521000|       |       |34.7825|       |
    |XXXXX01|1569560531000| 3.7825|34.7825|34.7825|34.7825|
    |XXXXX01|1569560535000|       |       |       |34.7825|
    |XXXXX01|1569560537000|       | 3.7825|       |       |
    +-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

When I run `df.show()` i will get output as above, But when i do a `df.count()` I am getting the below error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$UDF_E$1: (struct<NUM_ID:string,SIG1:string,SIG2:string,SIG3:string,SIG4:string>) => string)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at $line74.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$UDF_E$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:57
```

What might be the reason for this error ? any leads to resolve this?

Comment: Do we need to add null check in the UDF ?

Comment: Spark is very good at processing _only_ what is needed for the current step. The default parameters of `.show()` will only be 20 records, so once spark has satisfied that requirement, it doesn't process any more data. A `.count()` must process _all_ of the records, so there is some unexpected data causing the run-time exception. Your hunch about doing a null check is probably a good bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by adding a null check as below.

```
def UDF_E:UserDefinedFunction=udf((r: Row)=>{
val SigColumn = "SIG1,SIG2,SIG3,SIG4,SIG5,SIG6"
val colList = SigColumn.split(",").toList
val rr = "[\\}],[\\{]".r
var out = ""
colList.foreach{ x =>
if(r.getAs(x) != null){
val a = (rr replaceAllIn(r.getAs(x).toString, "|")).replaceAll("\\[\\{","").replaceAll("\\}\\]","").replaceAll(""""E":""","")
val st = a.split("\\|").map(x => x.split(",")(0)).toSet
out = out + "," + st.mkString(",")
}}
val out1 = out.replaceFirst(s""",""","").split(",").toSet.mkString(",")
out1
})
```